# Server side load a global component with Next.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, next.js

*The fact that I can't find anyone asking this question probably means that I'm not understanding something fully or I'm searching with the wrong keywords so please don't bite my head off if this is a stupid question.*

**I'm pasting the relevant parts of the code but if you want a repo of the full example, [here it is](https://github.com/jp26jp/contact-example). The full question will be at the bottom.**

---

Here's my folder structure:

```
server.js
/components
    Layout.js
/pages
    contact.js
```

---

**`server.js`**

```
// tells next which page to load
server.get("/contact/:id", (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = "/contact"
    const queryParams = {id: req.params.id}
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})

// api uri for grabbing contacts from the database
server.get("/api/contact/:id", (req, res) => {
    Contact.findOne({first_name: req.params.id}, (error, contact) => {
        if (error) return next(error)
        res.status(200).json(contact)
    })
})
```

**`pages/contact.js`**

```
const Contact = props => (
    <Layout>
        <h1>{props.contact.first_name} {props.contact.last_name}</h1>
    </Layout>
)

// a static async call passes fetched data into the props
Contact.getInitialProps = async function (context) {
    const {id} = context.query
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/contact/${id}`)
    const contact = await res.json()
    return {contact: contact}
}
```

**`components/Layout.js`**

```
const Layout = (props) =>
<div>
    <div>
        <Link href="/contact/John">
            <a>John</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/contact/Jed">
            <a>Jed</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/contact/Fred">
            <a>Fred</a>
        </Link>
    </div>
    {props.children}
</div>
```

---

I'm trying to figure out whether or not it's possible to dynamically query the database to build a navigation of the documents in the database. The only way I can think to do it is by re-rendering the entire navigation with every component but this seems extremely unnecessary. Again, if you want to give the code a try, [here's my example repo](https://github.com/jp26jp/contact-example).

Comment: do you mean you want to build dynamic navigation like `/contact/John`, `/contact/Jed`, `/contact/X` and `/contact/Y` from DB values? or you mean you want to preload all the contacts once and show different contact details by some id?

Comment: I want to build a dynamic nav from DB values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways I can think of is to use [custom app.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-app) and add `componentDidMount` method (it is fired only once) where you can fetch all the contacts, store it inside app.js state and pass it down to pages and components.

**_app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  // store contacts in the state
  state = {
    contacts: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // get contacts and store them in the _app.js state
    fetch('some-api/all-contacts-endpoint').then(contacts => {
       this.setState({ contacts });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} contacts={this.state.contacts} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**pages/contact.js**

```
// contacts will be inside props here
const Contact = props => (
  <Layout contacts={props.contacts}>
    <h1>
      {props.contact.first_name} {props.contact.last_name}
    </h1>
  </Layout>
);

// a static async call passes fetched data into the props
Contact.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/contact/${id}`);
  const contact = await res.json();
  return { contact: contact };
};
```

**components/Layout.js**

```
const Layout = ({ contacts = [] }) => (
  <div>
    <div>
      {contacts.map(contact => (
        <Link key={contact.id} href={`/contact/${contact.id}`}>
          <a>{contact.name}</a>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Hope this helps!